# What's the most efficient way to batch mint NFTs?

Tags: tokens, gas, nft, batch

It seems inefficient to batch mint from the client side (eg. web3).

Apparently [Cargo does batch minting](https://docs.cargo.build/advanced-information/batch-minting-non-fungible-tokens) but I couldn't find their code.

My default approach would be a Solidity function that loops through an array of submitted metadata, like the following *pseudo*-code:

```
function batchmint(tokenarray){
  for metadata in tokenarray{
    minttoken(metadata);
  }
}
```

Is this an acceptable minimum? What's the best approach, especially in terms of gas?

Comment: As an alternative approach to batch minting, it seems like many people mint tokens individually at the time of purchase (to avoid minting extra tokens that are never sold).

Comment: Suppose the OP is creating a queue of on-demand mint actions and is trying to optimize for gas by batching them together every 2 min or so... Here is my answer: Looping is generally frowned upon in ethereum transactions due to it's runtime expense. But if you KNOW you are gonna mint X items... it is totally gonna be cheaper to batch mint vs individual mint transactions.